# Solving system of equations with three unknowns, but equations are missing components?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The equations are:

> 1. $ y * z = 8$
> 2. $x + z = 8$
> 3. $x + y = 6$

Solving for these gets me to:

> $z = \frac{16}{7}, y = \frac{7}{2}$ and $x = 8 - \frac{16}{7}$.

This is incorrect however. Putting it into a solver yields no solution.

Why can't this be solved?

Comment: btw, which solver do you use?

Comment: They’re not missing components. The coefficients of the “missing” terms are zero.

Answer (score 6):

$$yz=8\tag{1}$$

$$x+z=8 \implies z=8-x\tag{2}$$

$$x+y=6 \implies y = 6-x\tag{3}$$

substitute $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$, we get

$$(6-x)(8-x)=8$$

which is a quadratic equation, now you can compute the discriminant to check if there is such real $x$.

- If the discriminant is positive, there are two real solutions for $x$.
- If the dscriminant is zero, there is one real solution for $x$.
- If the dscriminant is negative, there is no solution for $x$.

Answer (score 4):

$z = 8 - x$ and $y = 6 - x$, then $$yz = (6-x)(8-x) = 8$$
which is 
$$x^2 - 14x + 40 = 0$$
The roots of the above equation are:
$$x_1 = 10$$
and
$$x_2 = 4$$
For $x_1 = 10$, we get $y_1 = 6-x_1 = -4$ and $z_1 = 8-10 = -2$.

For $x_2 = 4$, we get $y_2 = 6-x_2 = 2$ and $z_2 = 8-4 = 4$.

Therefore two solutions:

$x_1 = 10$, $y_1 = -4$, and $z_1 = -2$.

$x_2 = 4$, $y_2 = 2$ and $z_2 = 4$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype yes typo mistake .. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

With $(2)$ and $(3)$ one can deduce that $z$ is two greater than $y$ [e.g. $z = y+2$].

With $(1)$ we have
$$\begin{align}
yz &= 8\\
yz -8&= 0\\
y(y+2) -8&= 0\\
y^2 +2y -8&= 0\\
(y+4)(y-2)&=0\\
\end{align}
$$

which gives a solution of
$$(x,y,z)\in \lbrace (4, 2, 4), (10, -4, -2)\rbrace $$